# How to expose and use interface methods (e.g. send and recv) in a class based on asyncio.Protocol

Tags: python, network-programming, python-asyncio

I have subclassed `asyncio.Protocol` to create a TCP client that connects to some server.
I would like to **separate the lower-level interface from the application**, and create a layered architecture, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

I followed the example of the [TCP Echo Client present on the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol) and the way I start the client is also very similar:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_connection(partial(MyClient, loop),
                              '127.0.0.1', 8888)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

However, in my protocol I created two methods (service access points, technically) that provide services to the "N+1" layer:

```
def setDataReceivedCallback(self, fun):
    self.dataReceivedIndication = fun

def send(self, msg):
    self.transport.write(msg)
```

The `send` method would be used by the N+1 layer to send a message to the server (request), while the `setDataReceivedCallback` would be used to register a callback that is called when `data_received` is called (so that the protocol can issue an indication to the N+1 layer that some data has arrived).

However, I am not sure how I can get hold of those entry points.
To be more clear:

- `create_connection` needs a callable that returns a Protocol instance: so I won't be able to get hold of the instance at that points
- `loop` seems not to expose any of the coroutines that it runs - furthermore, once I execute run_forever I lose the ability of getting hold of the loop itself

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo and behold, the answer lies in the documentation.
From the section on [Creating Connections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-connections):

> Note protocol_factory can be any kind of callable, not necessarily a
>   class. For example, if you want to use a pre-created protocol
>   instance, you can pass lambda: my_protocol.

This, translated into code means the following:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ThisClient = MyClient(loop)
ThisClient.setDataReceivedCallback(whateverFunction)
# And you can also use and pass around ThisClient.send at this point

coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: ThisClient,
                              '127.0.0.1', 8888)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```